# Log4J Console appender encoding

Tags: java, encoding, console, log4j

I have appender Console:

```
<Appenders>
  <Console name="SysOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%t/%level]: %msg%n" />
  </Console>
```

How can I say it what encoding to use?
There is nothing in documentation about encoding.

Comment: I found a solution (after 5 minutes of browsing log4j sources). It is as simple, as adding 'charset="CP866"' to PatternLayout, because it extends AbstractStringLayout that have such a field. So, for my xml it will be <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%t/%level]: %msg%n" charset="CP866"/>

Answer (score 0):

you can set character encoding like this:

```
<appender name="info" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">

<param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />

</appender>
```

Comment: No, I can't. I'm using log4j2.